# How to simulate a circular supply chain using SD in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, logistics, systemdynamics

I need a brazilian programmer to develop a circular supply chain using system dynamics in anylogic for my TCC. If anyone knows who already does this kind of work with a good price, please let me know.

I am no good at programming, and as I am close to my due date, I need help on the programming side, so I can conclude my final dissertation (my supervisor is aware and agrees with geeting payed help to support on this).